# PostgreSQL: Using LIKE to filter out last names that start with a 'K'

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

Table is called sales_reps which includes:
id, name, region_id

Example data:

```
id    |    name     | region_id
324133| James Kerr  | 2    
123456| John Doe    | 2    
456789| Terry Koos  | 4    
123678| Ana Mars    | 3
```

```
SELECT *

FROM sales_reps

WHERE sales_reps.name LIKE......
```

How would I finish this so that it only selects the accounts where the last name starts with a 'K'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASSUMING all names are Firstname Lastname

```
where sales_reps.name like '% K%'
```

Technically the above will select the accounts that have a space followed by a capital K.

If that cannot be assumed, then you can split the strings by spaces and check the last word.

Answer (score 1):

Using the regex operator, we can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM sales_reps
WHERE name ~ '\yK\S+$';
```

[image: demo of screen capture below]

### Demo